# What does 'Never act on tips' means?

Tags: meaning

This sentence is from 'How to Speculate like a Successful Trader',but I still can't understand what does that mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never act on tips* means,

> **Don't buy or sell any stocks based on tips** (when someone just gave you the tips)

This ***[tip](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tip_1#tip_1__4)*** means information or suggestions. It's quite common in stock trading that someone (it could be your friend, your stock broker, your analyst, news, or even a stranger) will ***[tip you off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tip-off_1)***. (For example, *"I heard that Acme is going to win the bid. I'm sure that will push Acme's stock up a few bucks."*, or *"They're going to announce a new policy tomorrow. There's still time to get out of the market, but you got to be hurry!"*)

The problem is, those tips could do you more harm than good, if you acted on it.

In other words, you should process all information carefully before you act anything in your trading.

In stock trading, there is a saying *[caveat emptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)*. It's Latin for "Let the buyer beware". Very good advice if you want to survive the market. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A tip is a piece of advice. If you get a tip about how to remove a ketchup stain from your shirt, it's probably worth trying. If you get a tip about investment or horse racing, its best to ignore it, unless you can check all of the facts yourself. Gamblers and traders circulate false tips in order to manipulate the odds in their own favour.